# codeigniter parse content in template

Tags: php, codeigniter, parsing, templates, view

Can someone help me to explain in which way is the best to organize views in codeigniter and make some template where header and footer will be same but content to change for every page? I use parse to send data from controller to view but don't know how to organize view in described way.

Also how to avoid php logic in view (if)?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways if your are not using a template library:

**1. Request your partial views in your content view:**

```
<?php $this->load->view('header') ?>
My content
<?php $this->load->view('footer') ?>
```

**2. Create a layout view, pass the content as variable:**

```
<html>
<body>
<?php echo $content ?>
</body>
```

In this case, in your controller:

```
// The true parameter means it will load the view, but just pass back as a string
$content = $this->load->view('mycontent', array(), TRUE); 

// Display the layout with your content
$this->load->view('layout', compact('content'));
```

As asking about the logic, don't get too strict with it. `if`, `for`, `foreach` are okay in a template. Forexample if a user is logged in, show a menu.

Comment: thanks, I will try now this second way. For logic how to use when I use parser, now I print variable in view as {name}, {lastname}, {city}, but how to say if active==1 echo active else echo non-active?

Comment: `<?php echo ($active == 1 ? 'active' : 'non-active') ?>`

Comment: You have to pass active variable to your view: `$this->load->view('page', array('active' => true));`

Comment: I did that, and I list everything normal, even active, but in if statement shows error.

Comment: I tried with {if active == 1} active {/if}, but doesn't work

Comment: I see, you are using template parser. I don't know how statements work in the parser... My example is for normal php view files.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you regarding about the templating.

Controller:

```
public function index() {
  $data = array(
    'blog_title' => 'Home',
    'blog_content'  => 'Content goes here..',
    'footer_data'   => 'footer data here..'      
  );

 $this->load->view(templates/header, $data);
 $this->load->view(templates/content, $data);
 $this->load->view(templates/footer, $data);
}
```

Note: imagine that templates is a directory inside your views folder. Inside your templates must be the header, content and footer.php files.